# table.whitelist wildcard in Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

in Kafka Connect source connector config I have this

```
"_comment": "Which table(s) to include",
"table.whitelist": "foobar",
```

How do I list all the tables as whitelist? does it take an array? can I use an asterisk `"table.whitelist": "*"`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to specify multiple options, separate them with a comma:

```
"table.whitelist": "User, Address, Email"
```

Or, if you want all tables, just don't include `table.whitelist`. By default the connector will pull all tables (and you can opt to expand this to views etc too if you want) that the connecting user has access to. You can restrict this by schema, and indeed with `table.blacklist` to include all tables *except* those that you specify.

Full syntax docs: https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/source_config_options.html#database

Comment: Can we whitelist all databases using wildcard or will have to mention every database as you said for whitelisting tables?